# Can no longer access Rails after installing Oh-my-zsh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently configured oh-my-zsh, but I am now unable to access Rails in my command line (both zsh and bash are throwing me an error saying I do not have rails installed and I need to install). I had already installed and worked fairly extensively with rails in the past prior to the installation of oh-my-zsh.

My `.zshrc`:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/Alex/.oh-my-zsh

export PS1="\w \$(parse_git_branch)"

# Set name of the theme to load. Optionally, if you set this to "random"
# it'll load a random theme each time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="awesomepanda"

# Imports nvm from bash profile
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"

export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
# sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git z h take)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/rsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias reload=". ~/.zshrc && echo 'ZSH config reloaded from ~/.zshrc'"
```

and my `.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

# Git
function parse_git_branch {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo "("${ref#refs/heads/}")"
}
export PS1="\[\033[1;32m\][\w]\[\033[1;33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[0m\] "
export EDITOR='atom --wait'
export VISUAL='atom --wait'

eval "$(hub alias -s)"

if which rbenv > /dev/null; then
 eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

Given these configurations, why would Rails commands no longer work?

Update:
Here is the error chain, when I try and run any rails command:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

When I do as instructed and run `sudo gem install rails`:

```
Error installing rails:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

I tried to update Ruby with rbenv, but this seems to only have updated Rbenv, so my efforts to simply reinstall rails have hit this wall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the rbenv initialization to your .zshrc file since the .bashrc file is no longer being used.

Comment: Which lines from the `bashrc` do I need to move over, and does it matter where I place them in the `zshrc`?

Comment: The last 3 -- beginning with `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then`. You can just add them to the end of your `.zshrc` file, though you'll need to restart your terminal or at least run `source ~/.zshrc` after you do that for the change to be picked up.

Comment: So I added the `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then` section to the end of my .zshrc file and relaunched my terminal, but it is still throwing the same error. I also tried using the `source ~/.zshrc` command, but it had no effect. I'll update the main prompt with more details about the error chain which is thrown when I try to use rails.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after installing Rails over ZSH. Just try this steps. I hope your problem will be solved.

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshenv
echo 'source $HOME/.zshenv' >> ~/.zshrc
exec $SHELL
```